# deploy REST services on glassfish 4

Tags: java, web-services, rest, glassfish-4

I cant get my REST services to start. I have one war file that includes my service.jar and in the service.jar i have my webservice with the following code

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import se.questify.entities.exam.Question;


@Path("/services/question")
public class QuestionWebService {

    @GET
    @Path("/ping")
    @Produces({MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN})
    public String ping() {
        return "ping from localhost webservice";
    }
}
```

When this is deployed to glassfish 4 (i run from eclipse) the webservice is not reachable at `http://localhost:8080/web/services/question/ping` (my context root is /web).

Anyone know why this is not working?

Web.xml

```
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">


    <display-name>Counter Web Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet> 

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Are you able to reach to your context root i.e. http://localhost:8080/web?

Comment: yes all other html and jsf pages are working correctly

Comment: Then it means your web services mapping is not correct. Can you share your web.xml. And how your services classes are exposed as REST?

Comment: I added the web.xml. DO you mean i need to do something more to expose the service other then using the Path annotation?

Comment: Which framework are u using to write your REST services?

Comment: Im using the standard built in to java ee 7 stack as you can see in the first code part

Comment: Thats interesting, do u get any exception in glassfish logs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't set a mapping to the REST servlet. You need something like this in your `web.xml` file:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Alternately, you can add an application class and set the mapping using `@ApplicationPath`.

```
@ApplicationPath("/services")
public class QuestionApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        final Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<>();
        // register root resource
        classes.add(QuestionWebService.class);
        return classes;
    }
}
```

And then set the `@Path` in relation to the mapped URL.

```
@Path("/question") 
public class QuestionWebService {
...
}
```

Comment: Notice there's no web.xml configuration needed anymore for rest services in GlassFish 4